# Defining new 'maximal' numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We will say that a natural nonzero number $m$ is a 'maximal' number if for any $n\in\mathbb{N}^*,n<m$ we have that the number of divisors of $n$ is strictly less than the number of divisors of $m$, i.e. $\tau(n)<\tau(m)$.

i) Find all 'maximal' numbers. (for example $6, 360,...$ are 'maximal')

ii) Are there infinitely many?

When I found that $360$ is a maximal number I thought that this is the reason why the degree is defined to be the $360$-part of a circle. It's easy to divide it in practice.

I wonder if there can be found other interesting stuff about them. Maybe they are already defined in literature, but I didn't see them yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smallest number with specific number of divisors](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496494/smallest-number-with-specific-number-of-divisors)

Comment: It's not the same. If you know the smallest number with specific divisor numbers does not guarantee that there is not a smaller number with a bigger number of divisors.

Comment: It's pretty easy to show that there are infinitely many, following because $\tau$ is not bounded.

Comment: @vadim123: Although I see similarities in the question content, I do not think this is a duplicate. Knowing the least positive integer $n$ with a given number of divisors says nothing about the comparison of the number of divisors for positive integers $m<n$ (except that it is not equal to $\tau(n)$ ).

Comment: For example,  $16$ is the smallest number such that $\tau(n)=5$, but $16$ is not a maximal number, since $\tau(12)=6$. @vadim123

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for
*highly composite numbers*.

This term was invented in 1915
by Ramanujan.

Do a search,
and ye shall find.