# $\tau (x) = 2016$ and for least $x = a \times b^2$ find $b$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisor-counting-function

> $\tau(x) = 2016$. For the least value $x$ such that $x = a \times b^2$ and $a$ has no square divisors in it, find the value of $b$.
>   [ $\tau (n) = \text{number of divisors of $n$}.$

This seems a quite easy problem. If $a$ and $b$ was prime then I would have solved it immediately. But they are not prime. So, I can't find a way to start with.

**Source**: BdMO 2016 question set 5 problem 8 (Higher Secondary).

Comment: isnt $\sigma(n)$ the sum of the divisors? $\tau$ is usually used for the number of divisors.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo opps.. Edited now

Comment: can you figure out what the exponent of $2$ in the factorization of $x$ is going to be?

Comment: Is it of the form $P_{1}^6*P_{2}^8$?

Comment: every number is of the form $a\times b^2$ with $a$ squarefree, you just have to find the smallest number with exactly $2016$ divisors.

Comment: Should I try numbers one by one ? >:(

Comment: No, clearly not, but you should look at the prime factorization of the number, what can you deduce about it? I get the feeling that this problem is not so much about one brilliant idea but more about making  a lot of little observations to prove that the correct prime factorization is in fact the best.

Comment: You may wish to consult http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496494/smallest-number-with-specific-number-of-divisors or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688956/find-a-smallest-number-which-has-exactly-n-divisors or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270226/how-to-calculate-smallest-number-with-certain-number-of-divisors

Comment: Read [Wikipedia on the divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) to get the choices for the prime factorization of $x$.

Comment: The smallest number with a given number of factors is given in [OEIS A005179](https://oeis.org/A005179)  Unfortunately the tabulation stops at $2000$ factors

Comment: Any thoughts, Rezwan, on the comments and answer?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Opps.. I was inactive a bit .. I got my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x=p_1p_2p_3\cdots p_nq_1^{2\alpha_1}q_2^{2\alpha}\cdots q_m^{2\alpha_m}$$
$$\tau(x)=(1+1)^n(2\alpha_1+1)(2\alpha_2+1)\cdots (2\alpha_m+1)$$ 
Since  $2016=2^5\cdot3^2\cdot7$ we have
$$n=5,\space \alpha_1=1,\space\alpha_2=1,\space \alpha_3=3$$

All number of the form $x=p_1p_2p_3p_4p_5 q_1^2q_2^2q_3^6$ where the primes are distinct satisfies $\tau(x)=2016$.

If we want to have a minimum $x$ we must have
$$x=2^6\cdot3^2\cdot5^2\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 17\cdot 19$$ The corresponding value of $b$ is $$b=2^3\cdot3\cdot5=\color{red}{120}$$

Comment: Huh? Isn't $x=2^63^25^2\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 17\cdot 19$ smaller?

Comment: Yes it is. I realized this when  I went to buy bread. Believe me, please.

Comment: You could also get $2016$ factors by deleting the $19$ and raising the exponent on $2$ to $13$ or the exponent on $3$ to $5$.  Both of these options increase $x$, but need to be checked.

Comment: I did not think about that possibility. Thank you.